# Team Foundation Server error while building and releasing

Tags: .net, tfs, nuget

I am learning how to work with TFS .I have three .Net apps which want to build and release them: one is a console application another one is a windows form application and the last is an ASP.NET web application.
When I build my console and windows form applications their build finish successfully but I can't release them. I got the following error:

> Solution not found using search pattern 'C:\Agent_work\06ec66ca5\ ** \ * .sln

But for ASP.NET  I even can't build it successfully and get this error:

> Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.DotNetCompilerPlatform'
>
> Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers'
>
> Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe

When I check my web application folder in sources in repository there were both packages install in them, I don't know why this error comes up.

Any guidance to resolve these issues is appreciated.

These are my settings in both windows forms and web application settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the result:

[image]

In release section it shows:

[image]

Build in web app:

[image]

That was all settings that I had.

Comment: Do you use vNext build or XAML build? Can you share the build definition settings?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I just followed the docs, I don't know which build I am using! How can I know?

Comment: What docs are you following? Can you share the link?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/overview I followed this guidance https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/dot-net

Comment: It is vNext. Did you changed any settings after create the definition? Can you share there settings?

Comment: @Eddi-MSFT Sorry for being late to answer. I didn't change any setting in build. I just chose Visual Studio Build, I even didn't change the folder destinations or search patterns. I will send the screenshots of them

Comment: One thing more , I don't choose Azure deployment for ASP.NET. I choose empty deployment and then in build task I added visual studio build.

Comment: You didn't publish the source code to artifacts, so the release cannot find the solution file. And why do you want to add the Visual Studio Build step in release definition, it should be in build definition?

Comment: First, where you see the green bar that says "Build Succeeded" on the build hub, choose Artifacts and expand it out and then post the contents of that.  Second, In the release section, did you link the artifacts to your build artifacts?  Check the artifacts tab in release.

Comment: I linked the build in artifact tab but I got that error. This time I did the same but didn't choose vsbuild in tasks and I got the release for windows form and console app but not for web app!

Answer (score 0):

You search pattern looks like it has extra spaces around the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

Add following arguments in "MSBuild Arguments" area of "Visual Studio Build" step:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

And then queue the build, you will get the build output for all the projects published into artifact drop folder(For web application, the output is a web deploy package). Now you can create a release definition and link to this artifact to deploy the build.

Comment: I copied  the above arguments in MSBuild but got the same error for web build : Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform' and .... the same errors as the picture above shows.